# How to run libgdx game on Windows or Linux without IDE?

Tags: libgdx

I made test task in company and in requirements there was a point which stated that on the machine where check will take place only JDK of the last version is established.
 I have an auto generated LibGdx Gradle project. An i think i need to write an instruction how to run project from the command line on Windows and Linux. Or may be run Jar file. But i don't know how to generate it in Eclipse.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, I understand your question correctly
You will create a runnable .jar in eclipse?

When you use Gradle you can write in terminal: `gradlew desktop:dist`.
Then you find a runnable .jar under `\desktop\build\libs\`

Here are some more links how you can create a runnable .jar from libgdx project:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765596/executable-jar-with-eclipse-libgdx

https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm

https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/web/selenium/export-eclipse-java-project-as-runnable-jar.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113692/create-executable-jar-file-under-eclipse

Hope it helps

Comment: This answer is essentially a link only answer: Without visiting other links, there's no way to know how to solve the issue at hand. While links per se are not bad, they should be there to _complement_ an answer, not _replace_ them.

Answer (score 0):

Build the game:

```
./gradlew build
```

Run the game:

```
java -jar -XstartOnFirstThread ./desktop/build/libs/desktop-1.0.jar
```